# PostgreSQL JDBC execute PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

While trying to run PL/pgSQL via JDBC driver (postgresql-9.4.1211.jre7.jar; using ANT) I get following error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"

Is there any way howto fix this via setting JDBC properties or changing the query of PL/pgSQL?

query:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  CREATE SEQUENCE id_sequence_SEQ OWNED BY id_sequence.id;
  EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table
  THEN
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
Position: 5
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2458)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2158)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:291)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:432)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:358)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:305)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:291)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:269)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:265)
```

Comment: Can you not just execute the CREATE SEQUENCE itself and then catch any potential exception from the Java side?

Comment: This code isn't really called from Java. It's a pre-installation ANT task.

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing a `DO` statement with JDBC and it works just fine.

There must be something weird in your statement. Try and log the statement by setting `log_min_error_statement` and `log_min_messages` to `error`. Execute the statement, then look at the message in the PostgreSQL log file. It should contain the statement that was actually executed. Examine it for weird characters and other strangeness.

Please also note that there is a syntax error in you PL/pgSQL: there must be something between `THEN` and `END`. For a no-op, use the statement `NULL;`.

Comment: None of that seem to work. Getting weird stack traces from JDBC. Thanks for the tip about NULL;